# How to decompile jhipster based war file

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster, decompiler

Hi I have tried to decompile the classes of a jhipster generated war file (non-obfuscated), but it's not showing decompiled version of the class file. I tried with normal jar (gson) and I can able to see the java code of that class.

[image]

It is showing null and i am not able to see the actual code.

Comment: Which decompiler are you using?

Comment: http://jd.benow.ca/ and i am using macos

Comment: It would be far better to simply fetch the sources for your version from Maven as the author suggests.  As a decompiler, JD-GUI is rather flawed.  You would have better luck with Procyon or CFR.  Better yet, use [Bytecode Viewer](https://github.com/Konloch/bytecode-viewer), which can let you choose between several decompiler back-ends.

Answer (score 2):

JHipster is Open Source, and the code you are trying to read comes from its library at [jhipster/jhipster](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster) - I think it is easier to read it there than trying to decompile the class file.

If you use Maven and/or a good IDE, you should also be able to download the source files, or at least attach them so they can be used instead of decompiling the .class file. Those source files are [available here on Maven Central](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/github/jhipster/jhipster/).

If you really want to decompile those files for audit purposes: I'm the one compiling them and doing those releases, and I don't do anything specific to obfuscate those. They are simply compiled using `mvn compile` with the latest JDK release on Mac OS X at the time of the release. So I guess your decompiler is pretty bad, you should try another one: the one provided by default in Intellij IDEA usually does a good job, you could try it.